# trying to get the value of a bool variable "should have the initial setting set"

Tags: dapps

I have the following public variable:

```
bool public saleIsActive = false;
```

but when I try to access from a test like the following:

```
let isActive = await myContractInstance.salesIsActive.call();
```

I get the following error:

```
1) Contract: MyContract
   should have the initial setting set:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
  at Context.it (test/myContract.js:21:55)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `"should have the initial setting set"` is the name of your particular test: you'll find it in `"test/myContract.js"`. It is not related to the error itself.
2. The actual error is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined". As you're calling `myContractInstance.salesIsActive.call()`, it means `myContractInstance.salesIsActive` is undefined.
3. Change the line in your test to: `let isActive = await myContractInstance.salesIsActive();` that's the correct syntax. [edit: as Jean pointed out in the comments, this does the same, it's just sugar syntax]
4. The issue is a typo: you're setting `saleIsActive` but calling `salesIsActive`.

Comment: Hey Kenzo, thanks for the help, unfortunately, salesIsActive() is a sugar syntax of salesIsActive.call(), so I get the exact same errors if a change my code as you suggest.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. The issue is a typo in your script - I'll update my answer.